# Make Image Change Size To Fit The Screen

Tags: size, screen

I have an image as a header which when the screen is smaller, for instance when the site is viewed on an iPhone or iPad the image is too big for the screen.

The image covers the navigation and makes the site unusable.

I need to find a way to make the image change size relevant to the size of the screen.

How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your container has a fluid width of 100% and can nicely adapt for different screen sizes. In that case you can use

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

and the image will never exceed its' parent container width.
Or some of the more sophisticated solutions from responsive design field:

> - [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/)
> - [Picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)

Comment: Really big thanks. Being trying to that for longer than I'm willing to admit!

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query in CSS.

In this example when screen width is less than 1024px it will set image max-width ot 100% of parent element:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    img { max-width: 100% }
}
```

Choose width by the maximum resolution of the device (iPad in landscape mode) for which you want to do it.

You can style anything else in {}.

But it still downloads full image for user.

More about media queries [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/).

Comment: Really big thanks. Being trying to that for longer than I'm willing to admit!

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and it sort of works. I am changing a span->list element->link and when the page refreshes it's as if my media styling is no longer there. Have you run into this or know what it happening?